# Does "development" also mean "action"?

Tags: meaning

> Many products utilize buttons in their design, which must
>   go through intensive development.

I think the sentence makes sense if I interpret "development" as "action", and the meaning of the sentence would be "Many products (...), which must go through a numerous times of pressing/using".

But can I interpret "development" as "action"? I looked up a dictionary, but the meanings are all a bit vague and not that close to "action".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Development" in this case is very similar to "controlled / guided evolution". It refers that many engineers / specialists work hard in order to design a product with buttons (or without buttons, as well). That engineering takes many steps some forward, some backwards, some to the side, depending on the outcomes of the tests.

"Action" refers to a specific (usually and relatively small) "activity".

We can say that "development" is a long chain of activities and actions.

In your sentence, development describes the products or the design (which evolve gradually under the work of engineers), and is not referring at all to the fact that the buttons must withstand many presses.